# Return different values from a vba user form depending on the button pressed

Tags: vba, excel

I have been creating an acronym finding macro that will sit on a custom toolbar in word. When run it searches the document for acronyms and places them in a table. I want to include some user forms so that as the macro finds an acronym the user can select the predefined definition (got from an excel document) or enter their own new one (I know multiple acronyms meanings is frowned upon but it happens).

Anyway I am stuck. I have created a user form with three buttons. A text input and a label. Now I have managed to set the label text with the acronym that was found however I can't seem to get the buttons to change a variable, userChoice, and if applicable save the newly entered definition.

below is the test macro i have been trying this out on

```
Sub userFormTest()

Dim objExcel As Object
Dim objWbk As Object
Dim rngSearch As Object
Dim rngFound As Object
Dim targetCellValue As String
Dim userChoice As Integer

Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWbk = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Dave\Documents\Test_Definitions.xlsx")
objExcel.Visible = True
objWbk.Activate

With objWbk.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set rngSearch = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(-4162))

Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:="AA", After:=.Range("A1"), LookAt:=1)



If rngFound Is Nothing Then

    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = "Acronym:    AA" & vbCr & _
                               "Definition: Not found, please enter a definition below" & vbCr & _
                               "            or choose to ignore this acronym"
    UserForm1.Show

'an if statement here so that if the add button was pressed it adds to doc etc

Else

    targetCellValue = .Cells(rngFound.Row, 2).Value

    UserForm2.Label1.Caption = "Acronym:    AA" & vbCr & _
                               "Definition: " & targetCellValue
    UserForm2.Show

'an if statement here so that if the add button was pressed it adds to doc etc

End If

End With

objWbk.Close Saved = True

Set rngFound = Nothing
Set rngSearch = Nothing
Set objWbk = Nothing
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

I do realise that this could be done in the button_click() subs however I already have all the documents open etc in the other macro. Or is it possible to link to those already open documents? To be honest either way I would prefer to return to the main macro and just use the form to the user input.

Answer (score 2):

> I do realise that this could be done in the button_click() subs. However I already have all the documents open etc in the other macro. Or is it possible to link to those already open documents?

You can definitely link between `button_click()` subs and your main macro to modify the value of userChoice.

---

**Answer**:

What you need is some userform element (like a textbox) that can hold your value so you can refer back to it in your main macro. It looks like you already have this element (based upon your caption "Not found, please enter a definition below"). Let's say that element is a `TextBox` called Definition. Then let's say you want to return to the main macro after people push an "Add" button, as it appears you do (based upon your comment "so that if the add button was pressed it adds to doc").

In each of both Userform1 and Userform2, you would want something like this:

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click()

    Userform1/Userform2.Hide

End Sub
```

That would return you to your main macro, where you could follow up with:

```
If Userform1/Userform2.Definition.Value = Whatever Then
    'if the add button was pressed it adds to doc etc
End If
```

right where your existing comments are. Note that you could set `userChoice = Userform1.Definition.Value` here, but you don't need to because `Userform1.Definition.Value` already contains the information you need to track.

---

**Additional material**:

Rather than using the default instance of your Userform1 and Userform2 by using `.Show` on them immediately without assigning new instances of them to variables, may I suggest creating Userform variables to contain `New` instances of them like this:

```
Dim UnknownDefinition As Userform1
Set UnknownDefinition = New Userform1
UnknownDefinition.Show
```

Or if you want to get really optimal, you could follow more of the approach recommended here on how to make a properly instanced, abstracted userform:

[Rubberduck VBA: How to create a properly instanced, abstracted userform](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)

And now with bonus quotes from the post's author, @Mathieu Guindon:

> [make Definition a proper property, with the Property Let mutator changing the label value on top of changing its private backing field's value; avoid accessing form controls outside the form, treat them as private even if VBA makes them public.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44242921#44242921)
>
> [Calling code wants data, not controls.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037126/return-different-values-from-a-vba-user-form-depending-on-the-button-pressed/50051467#comment87120151_50051467) [You can extract properties/data, but not controls, into a dedicated model class.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44243057#44243057)

Comment: Aw, and I thought the quote would be "calling code wants *data*, not *controls*!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon As long as there's an edit button, there's room for more bonus quotes!